# Anonymous Users subsite

Tags: 2010, anonymous-authentication

I have a website enabled with ADFS authentication provider . Now i created a subsite and made it anonymous . But when i try to access the website , i am asked for credentials . I have made changes in Central Admin and set anonymous on subsite . What are my other options to check and make it work ?

Comment: Also Your page should be approved.. Try with clear page without custom webparts.

Comment: Have a look at this link - http://hosting.intermedia.net/support/kb/default.asp?id=2434

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved this by checking the two things that I list below:
If your site reads from some list probably it was not published some elements.
Check if it is also enabled anonymous access to the list from which you are going to read.

Comment: why did u paste my answers . . rolf